# What does **$$** mean when configuring PowerShell Command Line for DB2?

Tags: powershell, db2

I found [this article](https://www.xtivia.com/introduction-to-using-the-powershell-command-line-for-db2-on-windows/) that shows how you can set up PowerShell to act as your command line for processing DB2 commands.

In the article, it says that you can use the following command to configure PowerShell to run DB2 commands:

```
Set-Item -Path env:DB2CLP -Value "**$$**"
```

In the above command, what does the `"**$$**"` mean?

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside: a simpler and arguably conceptually more obvious form of the command is: `$env:DB2CLP = '**??**'`

Comment: Actually, it must be `**$$**`, not `**??**` to take an effect explained below.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein: You're right, the `**??**` should have been `**$$**`. That was a typo on my part. I have corrected the instances in the title and the question. Good catch and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It has a function, as distinct from a *meaning*, and the `**??**` is meant for the Db2 clp (db2.exe). Even if you are not using PowerShell (i.e. you are using db2cmd.exe or cmd.exe) this environment variable can be useful.

It tells the Db2 CLP to configure the current PowerShell session to be able to communicate with the background process `db2bp.exe` (the communication is IPC based) . Such communication is necessary because it is that background process db2bp.exe which maintains your connection to the database when you run `db2 connect to $your_database`, or equivalent cmdlet. The db2.exe manages the db2bp.exe so you don't have to worry about it.

The Db2 CLP knows which `db2bp.exe` it starts for your Powershell session and uses the environment variable `DB2CLP` as part of that.

Each individual `db2 ...` command line (or cmdlet) may quickly complete , and will act on the currently connected database, and you can run many db2 commands one after the other, or run scripts  - but all the time, it is the background task `db2bp.exe` that keeps your Db2 connection alive without needing to be reconnected (as long as the Db2 server does not itself end or kill the connection).

The `db2bp.exe` process will disappear when you run `db2 terminate` or end the process. You need to run `db2 terminate` when reconfiguring the node directory, or database directory, or when switching between different Db2-instances that are running on the same hostname, or optionally after `db2 connect reset`.